# Applescript to search within folder for photos with a keyword

Tags: applescript, photo

I want to write an Applescript to search for the photos within the Photos application that are returned by a multiple critera Boolean "and" search e.g two keywords, or album location and keyword. For context, further along in the script I will want to ask the script to copy photos returned by the script into albums created by the script.

The Photos AppleScript dictionary has a search command, but it only responds to text strings. There does not seem to be any way to refine the search to limit to a particular folder, or another search criteria.

I wonder if anyone knows how the search can be constrained to a boolean of two criteria?

I am new to Applescript any help appreciated!

```
tell application "Photos"
    set Srchres to search for "Defined Keyword" in album "Test album"
end tell
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Photos doesn’t expose the file paths - is that what you are wanting to use?

Answer (score 0):

Photos.app doesn't provide the ability to perform **search for** command in the certain album. Therefore, for your purposes, this command will be absolutely useless.

Instead, you need to use **whose** clause. Note that you should provide **full reference to album** following the structure of folders and albums in your Photos.app.

```
tell application "Photos" to tell album "Test album"
    media items whose name contains "Defined Keyword"
end tell
```

This is if I understood you correctly that you need to **search for media elements by a substring in their names**. If instead you want to **search for media elements by keywords in them**, then instead of the first script, use one of the following.

To search for media items by keywords you should use the **whose** clause as well. Note that the keywords is a **list of strings** (always). Also, note that you should provide full reference to album following the structure of folders and albums in your Photos.app.

Here is search example, which works with my Photos.app (Catalina OS):

```
tell application "Photos"
    set Srchres to media items of ¬
        (album "Untitled Album" of folder "Untitled Folder2" of folder "Robert") ¬
            whose keywords is {"Alexandra", "Untitled Album"}
end tell

--> Result: {media item id "0425380C-2C79-422F-90F8-0DFAB4FF3389/L0/001" of album id "F37876B4-6C89-4B78-90E8-78FF9287E199/L0/040" of folder id "22697ACA-E9AA-4720-BD03-8DF8B6D7E9DA/L0/020" of folder id "C8E0E9FC-57EB-4219-8EAB-BA4B3F34B5DC/L0/020"}
```

If you want to search only for **certain keyword** of keywords list, you should use "repeat loop" approach:

```
set mediaItems to {}

tell application "Photos"
    tell album "Untitled Album" of folder "Untitled Folder2" of folder "Robert"
        repeat with mediaItem in (get media items)
            if "Alexandra" is in (get keywords of mediaItem) then
                set end of mediaItems to contents of mediaItem
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

return mediaItems

--> Result: {media item id "0425380C-2C79-422F-90F8-0DFAB4FF3389/L0/001" of album id "F37876B4-6C89-4B78-90E8-78FF9287E199/L0/040" of folder id "22697ACA-E9AA-4720-BD03-8DF8B6D7E9DA/L0/020" of folder id "C8E0E9FC-57EB-4219-8EAB-BA4B3F34B5DC/L0/020"}
```

The last script in **handler form**:

```
on searchByKeyword:theKeyword inAlbum:albumReference
    set mediaItems to {}
    tell application "Photos" to tell albumReference
        repeat with mediaItem in (get media items)
            if theKeyword is in (get keywords of mediaItem) then
                set end of mediaItems to contents of mediaItem
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    return mediaItems
end searchByKeyword:inAlbum:

tell application "Photos" to set albumReference to a reference to album "Untitled Album" of folder "Untitled Folder2" of folder "Robert"
my searchByKeyword:"Alexandra" inAlbum:albumReference
--> Result: {media item id "0425380C-2C79-422F-90F8-0DFAB4FF3389/L0/001" of album id "F37876B4-6C89-4B78-90E8-78FF9287E199/L0/040" of folder id "22697ACA-E9AA-4720-BD03-8DF8B6D7E9DA/L0/020" of folder id "C8E0E9FC-57EB-4219-8EAB-BA4B3F34B5DC/L0/020"}
```

Comment: Robert Knaizidis - this worked first time, thank you very much for your help!!!!